Expectation of number of times simple random walk returns to the origin
Consider simple random walk. At each step wealth randomly either increases or decreases by 1. Denote with $S_n$ the wealth at $n$-th step and with $S_0$ the initial wealth. Let $S_0$ = 0. Let $N = \sum_{n=1}^\infty {I(S_n = 0 | S_0 = 0})$ then $\mathbb E(N) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty {\mathbb P(S_n = 0 | S_0 = 0})$. Let $r = \mathbb P(S_n = 0 \text{ for some }n \geq 1 |S_0 = 0)$ (as defined in the textbook). I assume $r = \mathbb P(N \geq 1) = 1 - \mathbb P(N = 0) = 1- \mathbb P(S_n \neq 0 \,\forall n \geq 1 | S_0 = 0)$. My textbook claims that $\mathbb E(N) = \dfrac{r}{1-r}$. But I'm not sure how it gets there and need hints.
Thanks in advance.

I would look at how $E[N]$ and $E[N \mid N\ge 1]$ are related (two different ways, one of which involves $r$ and the other memorylessness)  and then solve the simultaneous equations. Another approach would be to identify a suitable geometric distribution.

Thanks @Henry. In the end i stumbled upon this solution: let $r_k = P(N=k|S_0=0), r = P(N\geq1), r_0 = 1-r$, then if shown that $r_k = r^k(1-r)$, $E(N) = (1-r)\sum kr^k = r(1-r)( \dfrac{1}{1-r})' = r/(1-r)$.

You have found your own solution, similar to the second of the two possible approaches in my earlier comment:

You can say $\mathbb E[N]= \mathbb P( N \ge 1) \, \mathbb E[N \mid N \ge 1]= r \, \mathbb E[N \mid N \ge 1]$ and also with memorylessness $E[N \mid N \ge 1] = 1+\mathbb E[N]$ and solving these as simultaneous equations gives  $\mathbb E[N]=\frac{r}{1-r}$.

You can say $\mathbb P( N = k) = r^k(1-r)$ as the probability you return $k$ times and then never again, so $N$ has a geometric distribution with parameter $1-r$ and $\mathbb E[N] = \sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty k\, P( N = k) =  \sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty k \,r^k(1-r) = \frac{r}{1-r}$.


